# Web Site —— how to launch local Google Map App by Web Url

Tags: android, google-maps, web

i just want to launch the google map app had been install in the android mobile by web site url.

Does anyone esle know the solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can perform this using an intent. replace START_ADD with current location or location you want the map to focus on.

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=START_ADD";

startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(url)));
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question. try this <a href="geo:lat, lng;">open map</a>

Comment: It is my fault.I did not describe the problem clear.Can i send an address directly,just as —— 75 Waterloo Road, Kowloon, Hong Kong.

Comment: use this uri scheme geo:0,0?q=my+street+address. check this developer respurce for more info. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

Comment: It works under android by opening the address in the browser, but it does not work under iphone's safari browser. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a lat lng location where you want the center of the map to be.

For example:

> http://maps.google.co.uk/?ll=53.385517,-1.865315

Comment: Thank you so much.I want to open google map app after click the address.For example, the code is like this —— <a href="....">75 Waterloo Road, Kowloon, Hong Kong</a>